# Wrap all cents values in a string with superscript

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, currency

I have a string that could be something like "$2.99" or could be "$1.99 - $20.99" with multiple prices in the string.

I would like to wrap the cents in a superscript tag.

So far I have been trying:

```
$price = [could be "$x.xx" or could be "$x.xx - $xx.xx"];
$pattern = '/(\$[\d,]+\.)(\d+)([\s\-]*\$[\d,]*\.*)(\d*)(.*)$/';
$formattedPrice = preg_replace($pattern, '$1<sup>$2</sup>$3<sup>$4</sup>$5', $price);
```

But that only matches "$x.xx - $xx.xx" not just "$x.xx"

Is there a good way to just find all instances of a period and wrap the next two characters?

Thanks.

Comment: replace `/(?<=\d\.)\d{2}(?!\d)/` with `<sup>$0</sup>`? [see here](http://regex101.com/r/aY1pW4/3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pattern = '/\.([\d]{2})/';
```

This pattern will match any two digits that are directly following a period.

```
preg_replace($pattern, '.<sup>$1</sup>', '$2.99');
preg_replace($pattern, '.<sup>$1</sup>', '$1.99 - $20.00');
```

Output:

```
string(16) "$2.<sup>99</sup>"
string(36) "$1.<sup>99</sup> - $20.<sup>00</sup>"
```

If you wanted to guard against not selecting any random two digits following a period but specifically in a dollar amount, you can add to it to ensure you're correctly targetting the right substrings with this pattern:

```
$pattern = '/\$\d\.([\d]{2})/';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to wrap the cents then you could use:

```
(\$\d+\.)(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/cH4kV0/2)**

[image]